# Node.js server middleware behaves differently on AKS cluster than when server runs locally

Tags: node.js, flutter, kubernetes, azure-aks, request-headers

I'm deploying my Node.js server on AKS and I'm experiencing a few unexpected behaviours not happening on my local machine. I've tried various things to debug it but I'm not succeeding at all.

I use a Middleware as

```
exports.clientApiKeyValidation = (req, res, next) => {

   try {
      const clientApiKey = req.get('api_key');
      console.log(`received api_key is ${clientApiKey}
      and expected API_KEY is ${process.env.API_KEY}`);
      const receivedTypeof = console.log('clientApiKey ', typeof clientApiKey);
      const expectedTypeof = console.log('expected ', typeof process.env.API_KEY);
      console.log('req.headers is: ', req.headers);
      if (!clientApiKey) {
         return res.status(400).send({
            status: false,
            message: "Missing Api Key"
         });
      }
      if (clientApiKey === process.env.API_KEY) {

         // console.log('Api key correct');
         next();
      }
      else {
         return res.status(400).send({
            status: false,
            message: "Invalid Api Key"
         });
      }
   } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).json({
         error: new Error('Invalid request!')
      });
   }

}
```

used on routes like

```
router.get('/users', auth.clientApiKeyValidation, userController.findUsers);
```

In `app.js` I also set a few things, including a middleware function to allow this params as

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // either res.setHeader or res.header works.
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5000');

  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'https://xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'
  );
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'content-type, api_key, AuthToken, apikey'
  );
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5000');
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, api_key, Accept');
  // console.log(' res headers added: ', res.getHeaders());
  next();
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
```

I'm sending requests to it from my Flutter app adding headers like

```
    await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.getIdToken().then((idToken) {
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'api_key': Environment.dbApiKey,
        'AuthToken': idToken
      };
    });
    FixitUser? userDetails;

    // final Uri uri = Uri.http(Environment.dbUrl, '/api/users');
    final Uri uri = Uri.https(Environment.dbUrl, '/server/api/users');
    log('headers are $headers');
    await get(uri, headers: headers).then((resp) {
      log('UserMongoDBRepository.downloadUserDetails resp.body is : ${resp.body}');

...
```

When running the server directly middleware logs show it all works as expected

```
received api_key is hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh
      and expected API_KEY is hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh
clientApiKey  string
expected  string
req.headers is:  {
  'user-agent': 'Dart/2.18 (dart:io)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  api_key: 'hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh',
  host: '192.168.1.48:3000',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  authtoken: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVhNTA5ZjAxOWY3MGQ3NzlkODBmMTUyZDFhNWQzMzgxMWFiN2NlZjciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYW1lIjoidmluY2Vuem8gY2FsaWEiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9saDYuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tLy13TVNwMUxZd2hPZy9BQUFBQUFBQUFBSS9BQUFBQUFBQUFCSS9OdE43TTlTMEVIUS9zOTYtYy9waG90by5qcGciLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZml4LWl0LWI0YjAwIiwiYXVkIjoiZml4LWl0LWI0YjAwIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjc1Nzc1MTg2LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiWnhtejJHSmxNUlBXdjBMRGgyRDg4Y0o3T3V6MSIsInN1YiI6Ilp4bXoyR0psTVJQV3YwTERoMkQ4OGNKN091ejEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzU4NDY4MDAsImV4cCI6MTY3NTg1MDQwMCwiZW1haWwiOiJ2aW5jZW56by5jYWxpYS4xOTc2QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJwaG9uZV9udW1iZXIiOiIrMzkzNjYxNDcxMzEzIiwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJnb29nbGUuY29tIjpbIjExNjkyMTg2MTcwOTA0NTM5MzU5MiJdLCJwaG9uZSI6WyIrMzkzNjYxNDcxMzEzIl0sImVtYWlsIjpbInZpbmNlbnpvLmNhbGlhLjE5NzZAZ21haWwuY29tIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoiZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSJ9fQ.ZNJFrxWlycMVgg4VAdWt6Q0WR5yrWPar5_UJwhQ9-hVX25aKC69yDpoM2adx3OIQ-hlsGz1bNvVEUSfvWUWRWF-TaX2TVeLb5z0blAtl8A1cGcvnaryffr0jpCtN_nhDg3WTtHw4B2USDe432TxSXx0ICrk8bx_fum8jsfBvAh_xU8bnr6lLsc0pltcmU-zun0rhZcC6jpxua2d0jIwWyWSXurjNBkLkduzOpUbw6KCLur7wVcxz-HmuD67D0qx5dr37malLbOBt5mcfOtdJEJcEq55XqXqUanopT_OWTWxByMrD_CXyZnLu_q1DgSBMM4kaLrSA14ETD_EvIeqHOQ',
  
}
```

When instead is running on AKS cluster `api_key` is missing from received request headers as the logs show, so the middleware responds with `{"status":false,"message":"Missing Api Key"}`

```
received api_key is undefined
      and expected API_KEY is some api key

req.headers is:  {
  host: 'xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com',
  'x-request-id': '2ecc2ec74c808cf40f816921374f72d4',
  'x-real-ip': '81.56.11.23',
  'x-forwarded-for': '81.56.11.23',
  'x-forwarded-host': 'xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com',
  'x-forwarded-port': '443',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'x-forwarded-scheme': 'https',
  'x-scheme': 'https',
  'user-agent': 'Dart/2.18 (dart:io)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  authtoken: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVhNTA5ZjAxOWY3MGQ3NzlkODBmMTUyZDFhNWQzMzgxMWFiN2NlZjciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.d8emU2BKNBV5oe3YQVHT8M8otFos_RvEmeyutdmYBDhnzyPgMZTAn_l3JikRAbcTNdDOAVoutZgTb5s8d6di3plAoE240OwwZTuSwxVpSaS7fDPt_rjQf9k2RmVsRa-fq1SWIP2ejdEbma_QngLSpXO0-PSPx4wa7mThjv2enP00TpUB9RDsOPK2QKlwOX9i1gc1_7kOPGJwouG3S3W4_kOXIxSoVjAT0P9k2xtHa99W-_gwn-9YqM1UoHrLkEs-ONKpe5SWLIet9r_PvI2l1zqb-1fGBmoeBhyzSijw_cOLJSayEoImtkCOmAA0rhMNYc--Yxuzd8EMyyp1U9dThg'
}
```

The headers prints from Flutter shows the api_key being correctly set.

```
headers are {Content-Type: application/json, api_key: some api key, AuthToken: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVhNTA5ZjAxOWY3MGQ3NzlkODBmMTUyZDFhNWQzMzgxMWFiN2NlZjciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.d8emU2BKNBV5oe3YQVHT8M8otFos_RvEmeyutdmYBDhnzyPgMZTAn_l3JikRAbcTNdDOAVoutZgTb5s8d6di3plAoE240OwwZTuSwxVpSaS7fDPt_rjQf9k2RmVsRa-fq1SWIP2ejdEbma_QngLSpXO0-PSPx4wa7mThjv2enP00TpUB9RDsOPK2QKlwOX9i1gc1_7kOPGJwouG3S3W4_kOXIxSoVjAT0P9k2xtHa99W-_gwn-9YqM1UoHrLkEs-ONKpe5SWLIet9r_PvI2l1zqb-1fGBmoeBhyzSijw_cOLJSayEoImtkCOmAA0rhMNYc--Yxuzd8EMyyp1U9dThg}
```

So as a test instead of `api_key` I used `apikey` and it gets retrieved in the request, but then the `===` check fails so the middleware responds with `{"status":false,"message":"Invalid Api Key"}` even it their type and value are identical, as checked here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

```
received api_key is hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh
      and expected API_KEY is hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh

clientApiKey  string
expected  string
req.headers is:  {
  host: 'fixit1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com',
  'x-request-id': '515ad2a00b1a3db24a69e09f6d181036',
  'x-real-ip': '81.56.11.23',
  'x-forwarded-for': '81.56.11.23',
  'x-forwarded-host': 'fixit1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com',
  'x-forwarded-port': '443',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'x-forwarded-scheme': 'https',
  'x-scheme': 'https',
  'user-agent': 'Dart/2.18 (dart:io)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  authtoken: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVhNTA5ZjAxOWY3MGQ3NzlkODBmMTUyZDFhNWQzMzgxMWFiN2NlZjciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.lDMgmTJkrm6ZnoyEU1F7Sjoo7Y8or8ZKzIrwBJ9ssQiR8yN5KD2ZhyM6yyR_Arscmyg1ZV_6RsTnFgGsVsmjiMzyX6TOXmYkmRlvvMjjjFsV8rW_W_gIdVld6vSg-JMrOlLcCeBknFDJC50bbNGYBSwQ2_C_MZIKlbFWWrqME988MOiUBlyT86t5Oofc5uVMETrpBf0a-wsFRdyEX-3uj-T3MRHza62PTcpHURoptQdIzYsBSc6WxR6WCINVjx__DbWlWrGt612Mw4iLv1XReiGriQEjTDc9cXbG0ngbiRsn0ojvZ-Jb8Pb6kj7gWRYDRsKFg2nxxFMhVeSDuIeO-w',
  apikey: 'hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh'
}
```

As a second test I changed the `===` operator to `==` in the middleware but still it returns false and responds with `{"status":false,"message":"Invalid Api Key"}`.

Then I tried to use `const serverApiKey = JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY);` and `const clientApiKey = JSON.stringify(req.get('apikey'));` for the comparison and they actually do yield different results

```
clientApiKey json string is:  "hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh"
serverApiKey json string is:  "hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh\n"
```

`env.API_KEY` does get it's value from a k8s secret, base64 encoded with `echo -n hjkdiu-slia7h-si9udd989jw-ols8dh |base64` command. To see if it was a matter of an empty space in the encoded value from the secret I tried encoding it with and without the `-n` flag but they result in the same json encoded string.

I'm not sure it could have something to do with the docker image I create so here's the `Dockrfile`

```
FROM node:18.3.0
WORKDIR /usr/app
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY ./ package.json ./
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
# Istall the dependencies

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY ./ ./


# Add the following lines for create-react-app bug, workaround
ENV CI=true
ENV WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

1. Why `api_key` param is not present while `apikey` param is in the received request headers?
2. Why the `\n` in the `serverApiKey` but not in the `clientApiKey` ?
3. Why is this happening only on AKS and not on my local machine?

Thank you very much as always.

Comment: Some HTTP server implementations don't accept underscores in HTTP header names.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you very much. Indeed it seems that it was the first problem, but it has been an easy fix. Now the problems is that the api key I send from the client doesn't match the server api key, coming from a base64 encoded value in the server-secret, so the middleware responds with the `wrong key` message. I updated the question body to show my tests. Any suggestion about it? I'm going in circles

Comment: I don't know anything about AKS, but I would probably just chalk it up to a platform thing and use `process.env.API_KEY.trim()` (or `.trimEnd()`)

Comment: yeap, not sure either about the reason of it, but the /n made me think about added spaces.. Ive tried .trim() and it was it! Thank you so much. Would you make it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about AKS, but some HTTP server implementations (for instance [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers)) don't accept underscores in HTTP header names.

As for why the server API keys contains a trailing newline: it may be a platform thing. I would just be pragmatic about it and remove it before use: `process.API_KEY.trim()`

Comment: Thank you very much again. I'm gonna use `.trim()` all over the place.. I'm adopting a zero trust policy here lol.